# Which way does the fluid flow?

Tags: flow, fluid-statics

[image: Question Figure]

In the given siphon arrangement if a hole is made at D, will water leak out or will air leak in?

I think air should leak in as fluids flow from high to low pressure but I'm not sure...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the pressure in the siphon tube.  Inside the container, at the bottom of the tube, the pressure is equal to the ambient pressure at that point, which is obviously above atmospheric pressure due to the water column that is above that point.  As you go up the tube, the pressure decreases because there is less water column above that point than there was at the bottom of the tube.  At the water surface, the pressure inside the tube is equal to atmospheric pressure, ignoring the very small pressure drop in the tube that occurs due to the flow rate through the tube.  Continuing on, at points of the tube that are above the water surface, the pressure is lower than atmospheric pressure.  Thus, the pressure at point "D" is below atmospheric pressure, so a hole there would suck air into the tube and "break" the siphon.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that air will leak in, assuming that $h_1$ is low enough for the siphon to work.